# NestJs How to use controller on a microservice?

Tags: controller, nestjs, microservices

I have a monolith project with 2 microservices using NestJs/Microservices and Redis for connection trough.

What I need to achieve:

1. create a controller on microservice and handle an endpoint named (/external).

The problem:

1. controller on microservice dont receive http requests.

Details:

my microservice main.ts:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { OfferModule } from './offer.module';
import { Transport, RedisOptions } from '@nestjs/microservices';

async function bootstrap() {
  // const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(OfferModule, {
  //   name: 'OFFER_SERVICE',
  //   transport: Transport.REDIS,
  //   options: {
  //     host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || 'redis',
  //     port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
  //   },
  // } as RedisOptions);

  const appMicroservice = await NestFactory.create(OfferModule, {
    cors: {
      origin: true,
      credentials: true,
    },
  });

  appMicroservice.connectMicroservice({
    name: 'OFFER_SERVICE',
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: {
      host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || 'localhost',
      port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
    },
  });

  await appMicroservice.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

my controller offer.controller.ts

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Inject, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { OfferService } from './offer.service';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { OfferMicroserviceEventsEnum } from './enums/offer-microservice-events.enum';
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Controller('please_work')
export class OfferController {
  constructor(
    private readonly _offerService: OfferService,
    @Inject('OFFER_SERVICE') private readonly client: ClientProxy,
  ) {}

  @Get('/')
  getHello() {
    return 'Hello from offer microservice';
  }
  @Post('/1')
  async completeTask(@Body() data: any) {
    return await lastValueFrom(
      this.client.send(OfferMicroserviceEventsEnum.COMPLETE_TASK, data),
    );
  }
}
```

im starting my project with docker.
Here is my stdout:

```
[6:18:53 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...
offer-microservice  | 
offer-microservice  | [6:18:55 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
offer-microservice  | 
offer-microservice  | [Nest] 42  - 10/09/2023, 6:18:55 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
offer-microservice  | [Nest] 42  - 10/09/2023, 6:18:55 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] OfferModule dependencies initialized +33ms
offer-microservice  | [Nest] 42  - 10/09/2023, 6:18:55 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] OfferController {/please_work}: +9ms
offer-microservice  | [Nest] 42  - 10/09/2023, 6:18:55 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/please_work, GET} route +1ms
offer-microservice  | [Nest] 42  - 10/09/2023, 6:18:55 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/please_work/1, POST} route +0ms
offer-microservice  | [Nest] 42  - 10/09/2023, 6:18:55 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
```

As we can see the route is mapped , but however im trying to access it im getting 404.
(get request to: http://localhost:3000/please_work)

[image]

Edit:

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  offer-microservice:
    container_name: offer-microservice
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    entrypoint: [ "yarn", "start:dev" ]
    networks:
      - test

networks:
  test:
    external: true
```

Comment: What does your `docker-compose` look like? Are you exposing the container's port 3000 to your local machine's port 3000?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I added my docker-compose code here. "Are you exposing the container's port 3000 to your local machine's port 3000?": Im not sure, but I have a similar monolith in this project and it works great, it have a similar docker-compose file and similar main.ts file (But in the monolith main.ts file Im starting all microservices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the ports to your docker-compose so that docker knows to map your machine's port 3000 to this container's port 3000. Your new docker-compose should look something like this:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  offer-microservice:
    container_name: offer-microservice
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    entrypoint: [ "yarn", "start:dev" ]
    networks:
      - test
    ports
      - '3000:3000'

networks:
  test:
    external: true
```

The [external option of the network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/06-networks/#external) is probably not what you expect it to be, as it means that you're using a network created outside of the docker compose application. Unless you specifically have a Docker network set up that you plan to use, you can remove that option. The added `ports` section is still necessary though, so that your local machine knows where to send requests to port 3000